# Why automatic error execution on Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Why the execution of this function is giving me the error?

```
Function aaaaaa() As Boolean

Error1:
    MsgBox "hi guys"
    Exit Function

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: If there is an error, you will execute the **MsgBox**.  If there is no error, you will still execute the **MsgBox**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have a "Goto" line defined, doesn't mean it will run only if called.  Add an `Exit Sub` before you define the error block, so the code will exit before then.

You likely want something like:

```
Function aaaaaa() As Boolean
If [SOMETHING] Then 
    GoTo Error1
Else
    aaaaaa = True
End If    
Exit Function
Error1:
    MsgBox "hi guys"
    Exit Function

End Function
```